# change a dataframe row value with dynamic number of columns spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe (contains 10 columns) for which I want to change the value of a row (for the last column only). I have written following code for this:

```
 val newDF = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(WRADF.rdd.map(r=> {
      Row(r.get(0), r.get(1),
          r.get(2), r.get(3),
          r.get(4), r.get(5),
          r.get(6), r.get(7),
          r.get(8), decrementCounter(r))
     }), WRADF.schema)
```

I want to change the value of a row for 10th column only (for which I wrote `decrementCounter()` function). But the above code only runs for dataframes with 10 columns. I don't know how to convert this code so that it can run for different dataframe (with different number of columns). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for posting a question. Please finish the tour and enjoy SO ;-) (someone else seems to edit your post. Remove ">"  and "regards thingy" from the general text please).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do something like this. Define `udf`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf._

val decrementCounter = udf((x: T) => ...) // adjust types and content to your requirements

df.withColumn("someName", decrementCounter($"someColumn"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for posting an answer. Please finish the tour and enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think UDF will be a better choice because it can be applied using the Column name itself.

For more on udf you can take a look here : https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html

For your code just use this :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf._

val decrementCounterUDF = udf(decrementCounter _) 

df.withColumn("columnName", decrementCounterUDF($"columnName"))
```

What it will does is apply this decrementCounter function on each and every value of column `columnName`.

I hope this helps, cheers !